# How to use rule inside another rule in css?

Tags: css, css-selectors

What I'm asking for is a bit strange I think, but I have no other way.
Is there a way to do this pseudo css rule in real life:
let's say I have rule:

```
.myCssRule1{ color:red; }
```

And I can't (don't want) to change it but I need to use it in another rule I will made like this:

```
.myCssRule2{  
   .myCssRule1
}
```

Just like calling method from inside another one.
Any native way or JS library to do it ?

Comment: Not possible. CSS rules cannot be nested that way, other than in a few things like `@media` directives.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a CSS Framework like LESS to do this.

Code you write using LESS is then compiled into "native" css files.

An example here: check out `Mixins`: http://lesscss.org/

Below code taken straight from that LESS link

```
// LESS

.rounded-corners (@radius: 5px) {
  -webkit-border-radius: @radius;
  -moz-border-radius: @radius;
  -ms-border-radius: @radius;
  -o-border-radius: @radius;
  border-radius: @radius;
}

#header {
  .rounded-corners;
}
#footer {
  .rounded-corners(10px);
}
```

Using less this is compiled to:

```
/* Compiled CSS */

#header {
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -ms-border-radius: 5px;
  -o-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
#footer {
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  -ms-border-radius: 10px;
  -o-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Comment: I'm beginner in LESS, so I have question plz: I created a file called 'style.less' and add 'script' tag for less.js and 'link' tag for my new 'style.less', and that's it. why this is not working with me ? do I have to do any thing more ?

Comment: @Dabbas: Did you remember to put `rel="stylesheet/less"` in the link tag?

Answer (score 1):

You can't mix styles into selectors in that way using pure CSS. The way I would recommend achieving your result is to create a class with the properties you want shared, for example:

```
.red {
    color: red;
}
```

And apply that class to all the elements you want to be red. Any HTML element can have any amount of classes:

```
<div class="myCssRule1 myCssRule2"></div>
```

---

A *better* way (in my opinion) is to make use of a CSS preprocessor, which is a language often similar to CSS that gives you extra features, but compiles down to a normal CSS style sheet. My favourite one is [Stylus](http://learnboost.github.com/stylus/), but you should also check out [LESS](http://lesscss.org/), [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/) and [Compass](http://compass-style.org/).

Answer (score 0):

You would need a CSS preprocessor to do that.  The most popular are Sass and LESS.

- Sass (http://sass-lang.com/)
- LESS (http://www.lesscss.org/)